# Field x does not exist in model "res.partner" Odoo15

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

i would like to know why im recieving this error even thought my source code is correct.
the error :

> Field "contact_prenom" does not exist in model "res.partner"View error
> context: {'file': '/opt/odoo15/custom-addons/om_/views/x.xml',
> 'line': 3,  'name': 'res.partner.inherit',  'view': ir.ui.view(1981,),
> 'view.model': 'res.partner',  'view.parent': ir.ui.view(128,),
> 'xmlid': 'inherit_view_res_partner'}

My source code :
x.py

```
from odoo import models,fields

class x_respartner(models.Model):
    _name='x.y'
    _inherit='res.partner'

    #xx_nom = fields.Char(string="Prénom")

    contact_prenom = fields.Char(string="Prénom")
    channel_ids = fields.Many2many('mail.channel', 'mail_channel_profile_partner', 
                                    'partner_id', 'channel_id', copy=False)
```

x.xml

```
<record id="inherit_view_res_partner" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='street']" position="after">
            <field name="contact_prenom"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

<menuitem
    id="xx"
    name="X"
    sequence="10"
    />
```

**manifest**.py

```
 {
        'name': 'X',
        'version': '1.3',
        'category': 'Hidden',
        'description': """
    Duplicated Contacts To Add Fields To Contact view.
    ===================================================
    """,
        'depends': ['base'],
        'data': [
            #'security/ir.model.access.csv',
            'views/x.xml',
        ],
        'sequence':'-100',
        'demo': [
        ],
        'test': [],
        'installable': True,
        'auto_install': True,
        'application': True,
        'license': 'LGPL-3',
    }
```

i tried to restart the server and upgrading the module but i end up in the same error everytime
so please can you help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove line *_name='x.y'*

*_name* attribute is used to create a new table in the database. According to your code, you want to extend *res.partner* table.

You can review this [model inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/13_inheritance.html#model-inheritance) documentation for your future development.